# How to connect to sharepoint CRM document library with onedrive api?

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, onedrive

We have sharepoint online with site *CRM*.

I use  [OneDrive SDK for iOS](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-ios).
I can connect to main document library with onedrive api. I used usefull ["github example"](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/issues/119) to configure it.

```
resourceId: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/
apiEndpoint: https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/CRM/_api/v2.0
```

Web URL of this library is:

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/CRM/Shared Documents
```

This configuration is fine and works OK.

> I have trouble with another document libraries on this site.
>   Dynamics CRM creates his own document libraries. For example Acccount.
>
> I can open this library on Web. Browser URL is:
>      https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/CRM/account/Forms/AllItems.aspx

But I'm not able to connect to this CRM library.
I tried simple ask for children account:

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/CRM/_api/v2.0/drive/items/root/children/account
```

This API request returns error 404.

I also modified apiEndpoint to:

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/CRM/account/_api/v2.0
```

Result is the same. Error 404 - Not found.

**Help me with correct configuration please.**

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, your question is regarding SharePoint, not OneDrive or CRM.

Here's a reference to the REST endpoint for SharePoint: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx

If you want the items in an account library, you can use the rest api like this:
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/crm/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Account')/items